# Best way to set a MenuItem's sub-menu height?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

I currently have a menuitem (part of a context menu), with about ~35 menu items. Because of this, it causes the sub-menu to be huge. Even though I have scrolling ability, I would like to set the height of this submenu while having the ability to still scroll.

I've messed w/ the MenuItem.Itemspanel but have not been able to set the sub-menu's height and still scroll.

Comment: Not an answer, but I think you have some design issues here. 35 items are just too much for context menu. Have you ever seen context menu whith scrolling? =)
You can divide items into sub-menus, or better yet make normal menu or toolbar.

Comment: It doesn't dismiss the point that it should be possible. Windows does it.

Comment: @Xcalibur37, Windows does it? You mean that some Microsoft application has _context_ menu with scrolling? That\`s very interesting actually, can you give an example?

Comment: I am talking about the start menu scrolling. A context menu is still a menu object. You saw this functionality back before Windows XP (though honestly I shut it off most of the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, WPF does not allow this to be modified by properties. You will have to modify the default ControlTemplate.

**EDIT:**
I revised the blog entry on that [here](http://xcalibursystems.com/2013/05/customizing-the-wpf-menuitem-in-xaml-part-2/)

Here is a sample (notice the addition of "MaxHeight" on "SubMenuScrollViewer"):

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
    AllowsTransparency="true"
    Placement="Right"
    VerticalOffset="-3"
    HorizontalOffset="-2"
    IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    Focusable="false"
    PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
    <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
        <ContentControl Name="SubMenuBorder"
            Template="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=SubmenuContent}}"
            IsTabStop="false">
            <ScrollViewer Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true" MaxHeight="400" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer}}">
                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                    <Canvas Height="0" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Rectangle
                            Height="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder,Path=ActualHeight}" 
                            Width="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder,Path=ActualWidth}" 
                            Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" />
                    </Canvas>
                    <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="2"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ContentControl>
    </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
</Popup>
```

This is just to override the Aero theme. As you can see there is a lot of XAML for the MenuItem, so it's not graceful. Just make a separate ResourceDictionary to keep things tidy.

Comment: How would it be done w/out using the Aero theme? What would be replaced by "theme:SystemDropShadowChrome"?

Comment: In the blog I mentioned this link:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812
In there you can get the xaml for all 6 themes including Classic and Luna.

Comment: MS dropped the themes from their site. You can get it from my site, here: http://xcalibursystems.com/wp-content/archive/WPF_Default_Themes.zip