# Listbox in ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm  a WinForms user, so I'm new to WPF, plus I find that I'm using it more like WinForms.
Anyhow google didn't help, so I'm here.

I have added a listbox to a context menu, since the sub-items are about 50 so I thought it might be a good idea to have a list box.

So here are the problems, as you can see in the screenshot below, the listbox doesn't fill the menu and the background is highlighted.

Here is a quick code sample I'm using.

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
mi.Header = "test";
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.Height = 100;
lb.Width = 300;
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Width = 300;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lb.Items.Add("item" + i);
}
mi.Items.Add(lb);
cm.Items.Add(mi);
this.ContextMenu = cm;
```

[image: Screenshot]

So how do I fix this, or is there a better solution?

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a listbox as an *item* of a menu. That means the listbox itself is the selectable unit, not the individual items. That's why the background is highlighted -- the listbox item itself is selected and it's the item container that is painting as highlighted.

If you truly want to embed a ListBox in a popup, use the [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) class. But you would basically be re-implementing `ContextMenu` functionality. The best approach might be to accept the limitation of `ContextMenu`, complain about lack of a `MaxItems` property, and maybe try to implement that property yourself using a custom `ControlTemplate`. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527612/best-way-to-set-a-menuitems-sub-menu-height) for fixing the height, but that solution does not size to items.